# CakePHP Relational models: Completely ignoring model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a pretty simple relational model setup. When using `$this->model->find('all',$params)`, the results do not return the complete relational data set. I'm pulling my hair out here.

Here's my table setup:

**Table qs_skus:**

```
id (AI, PK)
sku_name
profile
...
```

**Table net_lengths_in_skus:**

```
id (AI,PK)
quick_ship_skus_id
net_lengths_id
```

**Table net_lengths**

```
id (AI,PK)
name
```

The way the models are configured are:

- Model QuickShipSku `$hasMany=array('NetLengthsInSku')`
- Model NetLengthsInSku `$hasOne='NetLength'`
- All models have `$actAs = array('Containable')`

When doing the following, I get only the first relationship queried, the last relationship is completely ignored:

```
$model = $this->QuickShipSku->find('all',
        array(
            'contain' => array(
                'NetLengthsInSku' => array('NetLength')
        )
    );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [QuickShipSku] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [sku_name] => 1112-8
                    [product_name] => Product A
                    [sku_specie_id] => 1
                    [members_ft] => 8
                    [profile] => Profile Description
                )

            [NetLengthsInSku] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [quick_ship_skus_id] => 3
                            [quick_ship_net_length_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
    )
```

For each `NetLengthsInSku` there should be a `NetLength`, but it's not even being queried.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of cake are you using?? I can't really answer this without knowing what version.

Comment: Whoops - thought I included that. it's 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a many to many relationship. That means an association called hasAndBelongsToMany.

If you are using Cake 2.x you should have something like this:

```
class QsSku extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'NetLength' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'NetLength',
            'joinTable' => 'net_lengths_in_skus',
            'foreignKey' => 'quick_ship_skus_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'net_lengths_id',
        )
    );
}
```

You should do something similar to your NetLength model as well.